# Oracle stored procured calling another stored procured and returning a cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need to have a stored procedure parse input and based on the results call another stored procedure.  The result needs to return a cursor.

My procedure is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TestProceuder1 (userData VARCHAR2) IS
    cl SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    --Amazing Logic
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT 'results' AS Results FROM dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
END;
```

Then the main do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MainProcedure (userData VARCHAR2) IS
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    --Amazing logic picking the correct procedure
    OPEN c1 FOR TestProceuder1(userData);    
        dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
END;
```

However, this returns an error of

> PLS-00222: no function with name 'TESTPROCEUDER1' exists in this scope

Why is it trying to call it as a function when TestProceuder1 is a stored procedure?

Comment: Try using an `OUT` parameter or a function instead of a procedure for `TESTPROCEUDER1`.

Comment: @stickybit so, when I move c1 to the out for TestProceuder1 then execute MainProcedure  I get this error:

wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TESTPROCEUDER1'

Comment: [This article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) shows how to process a return result from PL/SQL; but it's fairly complicated, so it might be worth considering a different approach. Do you actually need to use this mechanism - does a client end up needing to process the return result, in that form? Even if it does, will the second level of procedure (testProd here) also be called directly?

Comment: @AlexPoole This is approach is needed.  The client app needs to receive the results as if it was querying a table.    Splitting the stored procedures is desired as the logic in these while not complicated is long.  I really do not want to maintain a 500+ line stored procedure

Comment: OK, but will only mainProc be called, so only that has to return the result? Leaving you free to use a simpler mechanism for the split-out procedures? (If these were all in a package, as they maybe should be - only main would be public?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only MainProcedure will be called by the client, and the split-out procedures will not be called directly, then the handling for those can use standard PL/SQL mechanisms instead of `dbms_sql.return_result`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TestProcedure1 (userData VARCHAR2, c1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
    --Amazing Logic
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT 'results' AS Results FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Or you could use a function instead of an OUT parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestFunction1 (userData VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    --Amazing Logic
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT 'results' AS Results FROM dual;
    RETURN c1;
END;
/
```

Then the main procedure calls those, and only that needs to use the result mechanism:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MainProcedure (userData VARCHAR2) IS
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    --Amazing logic picking the correct procedure
    TestProcedure1(userData, c1);
    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
    -- or function
    c1 := TestFunction1(userData);
    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c81b3aff925721e6548e5041d8a25997)

---

It would probably make sense to put all of the procedures into a package, and only expose the main one; [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68e45edc75507ec05a3ab1caf87aaeeb).